# Input event Handling in blazor

Tags: blazor

[image: Ui]

I am searching for the logic of using only one parametrized Function to Calculate unit * rate onblur event and every rows calculation should be stored its corresponding amount input

I have just started Learning Blazor and I am having difficulty Implication this logic.

```cs
namespace Starterkit.Pages.Invoice
{
    public partial class Index
    {
        public DateTime DtpToDate = DateTime.Now;

        private decimal _unitPrice;
        private int _quantity;
        private string _description;
        private string _sku;
        private int _itemOrder;

       
        public event EventHandler<bool> HasChanged;


        public int ItemOrdem { get => _itemOrder; set => _itemOrder = value; }



        public string Sku
        {
            get => _sku; set
            {
                _sku = value;
                HasHangedField();
            }
        }


        public string Description
        {
            get => _description; set
            {
                _description = value;
                HasHangedField();
            }
        }

        public int Quantity
        {
            get => _quantity; set
            {
                _quantity = value;
                HasHangedField();
            }
        }
        public decimal UnitPrice
        {
            get => _unitPrice; set
            {
                _unitPrice = value;
                HasHangedField();
            }
        }

        public decimal Total => Quantity > 0 && UnitPrice > 0 ? Quantity * UnitPrice : 0;
        public string FormattedTotal => $"$ {Total:n2}";

        private void HasHangedField() => HasChanged?.Invoke(this, true);

        ///////////////////////////////
        ///


     
        protected enum UpdateFieldOn
        {
            Keystroke,
            LostFocus
        }


        protected UpdateFieldOn TextFieldInput { get; set; } = UpdateFieldOn.Keystroke; // defualt
        protected string UpdateOnText => TextFieldInput == UpdateFieldOn.Keystroke ? "oninput" : "onchange";
    }
}
```

---

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <label class=" fs-6 fw-semibold col-form-label">1</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="Perticular1" class="form-select  form-select-solid">
      <option value="">Please Select Perticular</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control from-control-solid la-money " placeholder="Remark" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input id=#if "InputUnit1" class="form-control from-control-solid " @bind="Quantity" @bind:event="@UpdateOnText" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input id="Rate1" class="form-control from-control-solid " @bind="UnitPrice" @bind:event="@UpdateOnText" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control from-control-solid " type="text" @bind:event="@FormattedTotal" disabled />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: No offense, but you haven't paid us to be software engineers for you.  Why don't you show what you have tried that didn't work, and someone can point you in the right direction?

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Please write in your native tongue than translate using automatic translation. It might turn out better...

Comment: @maciek I just want to perform calculation onblur event but i have to write code for every row separately is it possible to use only one function to calculate

Comment: @RobertHarvey could u plz elaborate

Comment: I think I know what you're asking now, but my Google searches are only turning up professional toolkits like DevExpress.  Let me look a little more.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes you are write My old logic of .net is not working where I create an function with parameter and just pass the values by calling them and setting them on the amount input. I just don't want to repeat the code for every Amount Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this model:

```
public class TableRowModel
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
}
```

And this variable in your Razor page's code block or code-behind class:

```
IEnumerable<TableRowModel> Rows;
```

This code creates a table that two-way binds each input to its corresponding field in the Model:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Value 1</th>
            <th>Value 2</th>
            <th>Result</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" @bind-value="@row.Value1" /></td>
                <td><input type="number" @bind-value="@row.Value2" /></td>
                <td><input type="number" @bind-value="@row.Result" /></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Change the code above so that each of your two input columns is hooked to a single event handler, like this:

```
<input type="number" @bind-value="@row.Value1" @oninput=@(() => OnValueChanged(row)) />
```

And write code in the event handler that performs your calculation.

```
private void OnValueChanged(TableRowModel row)
{
    row.Result = row.Value1 + row.Value2;
}
```

This works because you are using **two-way binding** on each of your input elements.

Comment: what is  Rows in @foreach (var row in Rows)

Comment: `Rows` is a member in your razor page's code: `IEnumerable<TableRowModel> Rows;`  You will need to populate it with some data by overriding `OnInitializedSync` or `OnParametersSetAsync`.

Comment: thanks of helping me your code worked and helped me a lot now I understand how some of the code work in blazor